# magento2 phtml image productpage location luma theme

Tags: magento2, product-images, image

which file in magento 2 controls the img alt description for the productpage?

i already looked at:

- `magento_root_directory/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image.phtml`
- `magento_root_directory/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/gallery.phtml`
- `magento_root_directory/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/image_with_borders.phtml`

But they don't control the `img alt` on the productpage.
My image code starts with:
`<img class="fotorama__img magnify-opaque" aria-hidden="false" id="magnifier-item-0" ...`

Comment: have you installed any custom theme or created one?

Comment: it's a custom theme, but the default luma theme also uses this

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Adding-quot-alt-quot-tags-for-the-product-images-in-magento2/td-p/54698

Comment: my final goal is to replace the alt text with the title. There is already a alt text available, but i can't find out which phtml creates this.

Comment: @Ronny - you want to replace alt text with static title ? actually its coming from block function name getGalleryJson() and parameter is caption

Comment: @Ronny - `alt="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getCurrentImage()->getLabel()) ?>"` this function in templates/products/gallery.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

check this 2 HTML files which contain alt attribute.

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/template/product/image.html

/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/template/product/image_with_borders.html
```

here you can file the alt inside `data-bind="attr: {src: src, alt: alt}`

you can change that to `data-bind="attr: {src: src, title: alt}`

I hope it will help you.